# XML Serialization for API

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I've been tasked with writing a library that serializes data to be passed to and from an xml API. I've never worked with this kind of technology before and am struggling a little bit. All the requests have numerous repeated fields so we were thinking of using a derived class to handle this. The xml looks this

```
<request>
    <UserId></UserId>
    <AccountId></AccountId>
    <Token></Token>
    <Method>
        <methodName></methodName>
        <Id></Id>
        <Date></Date>
    </Method>
</request>
```

We were thinking of then using something like this

```
public class Request
{
    [XmlElement("token")]
    public string token { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("userId")]
    public int userId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("accountId")]
    public int accountId { get; set; }

}
```

and then

```
public class Method : Request
{
    [XmlElement("methodName")]
    public string methodName { get; set; }         
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

I can get this to serialize no problem using   `XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Method));`

but it doesn't nest the inherited class and i can figure out how/where i can add the xmlElement("Method").
Can someone help me create the classes correctly?

**Edit**
I can make this work fine if i remove the inheritance from Method and include Method as class of Request - However with the multitude of different calls that we will have, I'm trying to make this a nice re-usable piece of code

Comment: have a look at the similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737363/serialize-nested-classes-in-c

Comment: Why would you want the extra "Method" element? Your "Method" is a "Request". The XML should be `<Method><token/><userId/><accountId/><methodName/><Id/><Date/></Method>`

Comment: Also, you may find it easier to skip XML serialization and just use LINQ to XML.

Comment: Hi John. Unfortunately its a 3rd party API. Dont get to change that.

Comment: Sorry, what does that have to do with the technology you use to create the XML to send to the API? You can use whatever technology you want to create that XML.

Comment: Sorry apologies for the confusion, that was with regards to your first comment. My boss is big on serialization and that is what he has asked me to pursue.

Comment: Use `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Method))`

Comment: Hi john. Thanks for catching that. It was just a type as i transscribed the real code out to something more legible. I edited my code so that it has typeof(method) instead of (request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i got it working. It outputs the xml as mentioned above in my initial question. I did learn something interesting things like not needing [serializable] and not having to set the [XmlElement] unless i need something different to my properties.

```
public class Headers
    {
        public string Token { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public Uri host { get; set; }
        public static string requestMethod = "POST";
    }
[XmlRoot("request")]
public class GetActivityDetailsByActivityId : Headers
    {
        public string responseType = "ResponseGetActivityDetailsByActivityId";
        public class MethodDetails
        {
            public string methodName = "GetActivityDetailsByActivityId";
            public int activtyId;
            public DateTime activityDate;

        }
        [XmlElement("Method")]
        public MethodDetails Method = new MethodDetails();

        public GetActivityDetailsByActivityId(int activityId, DateTime activityDate,Headers headers)
        {
            this.Method.activityDate = activityDate;
            this.Method.activtyId = activityId;

            this.AccountId = headers.AccountId;
            this.Token = headers.Token;
            this.UserId = headers.UserId;
            this.host = headers.host;

        }
        GetActivityDetailsByActivityId()
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need this class structure to nest a Method object:

```
public class Request
{
    [XmlElement("token")]
    public string token { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("userId")]
    public int userId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("accountId")]
    public int accountId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("method")]
    public Method method { get; set; }
}
public class Method
{
    [XmlElement("methodName")]
    public string methodName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

If you have a list of repeated Method objects in the XML, change this line

```
public Method method { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<Method> method { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this as its good info. I have a proper solution that i will put up when i get to it.

Comment: Thank you.  I look forward to seeing your solution.