# How to Serialise a List of instance nested within a class?

Tags: c#, list, class, serialization

I am trying to save a class into a file with serialization, it work for all proptiety but fail to Serialize nested class.

My class is suppose to represent a Task with a name,description ,... and it can be compose itself by subtask which is represent by a List of task

I have try to write [Serializable] before my list like explaine here:  [Serialize Nested Classes in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737363/serialize-nested-classes-in-c)

but I get this error: "Attribute 'Serializable' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on declarations."

```
[Serializable()]
public class t_Task
{
   private string nom;
   private string description;
   [Serializable]
   List<t_Task> subTask;
}
```

How to get all class in the list also serialize please ?

Edit: I am serializing using a methode found here: http://blog.danskingdom.com/saving-and-loading-a-c-objects-data-to-an-xml-json-or-binary-file/

```
public static void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
    }
}
```

Then i call it with a methode close to this one

```
public void Save()
        {
            GesionBinaryFileIO.WriteToBinaryFile<t_Task>(PathToFile, this);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`[Serializeable]` is not allowed on fields/properties and only needs to be put on the class.  Your class should be serializeable just looking like this:**

```
[Serializable()]
public class t_Task
{
   private string nom;
   private string description;
   List<t_Task> subTask; // Removed the [Serializeable] attribute
}
```

It is important to note that your `List<t_Task>` is not a nested class (it is just a regular class field), so the link you are referencing is not actually related to your problem.

`[Serializable]` is a relatively old method of marking for serialization. I would reference the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netframework-4.8) on `SerializeableAttribute` to see how your code could work.

**Here is a sample based upon the Microsoft article I linked:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace ConsoleOne
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class t_Task
    {
        private string nom = "test"; // Added for test data.
        private string description = "desc"; // Added for test data
        List<t_Task> subTask = new List<t_Task>();

        public void AddTask()
        {
            this.subTask.Add(new t_Task());
        }

        public override string ToString()
            => $"{nom}-{description}-{subTask?.Count}";
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task = new t_Task()
            {

            };

            task.AddTask();
            task.AddTask();

            // Opens a file and serializes the object into it in binary format.
            Stream stream = File.Open("data.xml", FileMode.Create);

            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            formatter.Serialize(stream, task);
            stream.Close();

            //Empties obj.
            task = null;

            //Opens file "data.xml" and deserializes the object from it.
            stream = File.Open("data.xml", FileMode.Open);
            formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            //formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            task = (t_Task)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();

            Console.WriteLine($"{task}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: There are many other avenues for serialization in .NET that are a bit more modern.  It may be worth reading about these as well. However, if you are only interested in a simple binary format then the above information should be sufficient.

- [Serialization in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/)
- [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: I have update my post to give more information about how I am serializing the class. Is it important to use XML ? I try to save them as binary

Comment: @Nux I don't think it's necessary to use XML.  If you look at my example I actually use `BinaryFormatter` as well.  Most of my answer is explanation.  I will update it to clarify what the important piece is for solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Thanks to it I think my issue is with the loading part and not the save part. i will create an other post if i don't solve it